# Accessing JSON through Jquery returns "undefined"

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm writing a small script to take Schedules from a JSON document and present them in list view. I'm having a hard time getting the right values to return when I access the JSON document, in continues to be "undefined"

Here's the JSON doc.

```
{
"Ferries": {
  "HorseshoeBay": {/*bunch of schedules here*/},
  "DepartureBay": {/*bunch of schedules here*/},
  "DukePoint": {/*bunch of schedules here*/},
}
}
```

And here's the JS

```
$.getJSON("includes/json/ferries.json", function(e){
    var depart = e;
    $("#content").append("<ul id='depart-list'>");
    $.each(depart.Ferries, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item.result);
    });
    $("#content").append("</ul>");
});
```

As you can see I'm just trying to log the results, but I come back with the number of values that are attached to the key "Ferries" undefined and I'm really not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Hey, so I tried with just using "item" as supplied by some commenters

my each function is now as follows:

```
$.each(depart.Ferries, function(i,item) {
            $("#depart-list").append("<li class='depart-list-item'>" + item + "</li>");
        });
```

Here I'm trying to populate with list items, of course predictably it returns a bunch of list items with the content of "[object Object]"

the HTML it returns looks like this:

```
<li class="depart-list-item">[object Object]</li>
```

Any further help would be great!

Comment: What happens if you just do `console.log(item)`?

Comment: Try to debug it with console.log(JSON.stringify(depart)); If e is indeed a valid json, you will see it in debug console.

Comment: Also, try to check your JSON with a validator http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @MightyPork Everything seems valid and I'm returning what i'd expect to see in the console. Will amend with a new problem in my original post.

Comment: @MightyPork My JSON returned valid, so we can rule that one out.

Comment: you could make a fiddle of it, then debugging will be easier.

Comment: @MightyPork Thanks for all the Help! I just needed to specifically target values in my arrays and that seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$.each(depart.Ferries, function(i,v) {
      console.log(i + "," + v);
});
```

Comment: That is not an answer, and since Ferries is undefined, will fail, too.